# How to format a date with parentheses

Tags: c#, parentheses, datetimeoffset

I want to *format* my date like :

```
From May 1 (10:02 pm) to May 3 (10:02 pm)
```

so I have this code:

```
Time.ToLocalTime().ToString("MMM. d, (h:m tt)")
```

Will this work?

`Time` is a regular `DateTimeOffset` variable in this case...

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: May be `MMMM d(h:mm tt)` here `MMMM` stands for the full month name (e.g. `April`) and `mm` for *leading zero* in case of minutes: `10:02` instead of `10:2`

Comment: What do you mean you don't know how?

Comment: `string result = $"From {time1:MMMM d(h:mm tt)} to {time2:MMMM d(h:mm tt)}";` where `time1` and `time2` are `DateTimeOffset` (or `DateTime`) variables

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, you have **2** variables, let them name as

```
  DateTimeOffset time1 = ...
  DateTimeOffset time2 = ...
```

And you are looking for a representation like `From May 1 (10:02 pm) to May 3 (10:02 pm)`.
If it's your case, you can try *string interpolation*:

```
  string result = $"From {time1:MMMM d (h:mm tt)} to {time2:MMMM d (h:mm tt)}";
```

Note, that I've changed your format string as

- `MMMM` for complete month name, i.e. `April` instead of `Apr`.
- `mm` to have leading zero for minutes: `10:02` instead of `10:2`.
- `.` and `,` are removed (they are not used in the proposed outcome example)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it to work.

```
using System;
                
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        
        DateTimeOffset time = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
        string newtime = time.ToLocalTime().ToString("MMM. d, (h:m tt)");
        
        Console.WriteLine(newtime);
    }
}
```

Comment: Output is Hello World
May. 2, (8:53 PM)

Comment: And what if it were 12:00? You might want to write some tests and check a variety of inputs.